# SAPUI5 use Papa Parse in Controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, package, sapui5

I'm trying to import the package Papa Parse and use it in my Controller (MVC).
Any idea how to do that please ? 
I followed this Tutorial: 
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/
but it didn't.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to see some code. The guideline seems to me as the right way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can show the code that is build and not working.